# What is the meaning of crossed https in url of sites

Tags: url

What is the meaning of https which is crossed by two horizontal lines in the website url ?

Answer (score 0):

http (Hypertext Transfer Protocol) is a system for transmitting and receiving information across the Internet. It is a simple request, and a response procedure is followed on the internet so that information can be easily, accurately and quickly exchanged between servers and software's which are trying to access it.

HTTPS URLs begin with "https://" and use port 443 by default, whereas HTTP URLs begin with "http://" and use port 80 by default.